# Android NullPointerException (getDatabaseLocked & getWritableDatabase)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments

I want to use Listview to display data in a SQLite database. I use a Fragment to get the listview. But now, I have a problem:

```
This is the Log info:
E/AndroidRuntime(12816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12816): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(12816):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
E/AndroidRuntime(12816):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(12816):    at com.tax_ui.sql.Inform_dbHandler.getAllInform(Inform_dbHandler.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(12816):    at com.tax_ui.fragment.InformFragment.init(InformFragment.java:72)
E/AndroidRuntime(12816):    at com.tax_ui.fragment.InformFragment.onCreateView(InformFragment.java:55)
```

This is the list adapter code:

```
public class InformListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Inform_item> inform_item_list;

    public InformListAdapter(Activity activity,
            List<Inform_item> inform_item_list) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.inform_item_list = inform_item_list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inform_item_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inform_item_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inform_item, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inform_title);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.inform_timestamp);
        TextView content = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.inform_content);

        Inform_item inform_item = inform_item_list.get(position);

        title.setText(inform_item.get_title());
        timestamp.setText(inform_item.get_timestamp());
        content.setText(inform_item.get_content());

        return null;
    }

}
```

And then, this is my fragment code:

```
public class InformFragment extends Fragment {

    private View mBaseView;
    private TitleBarView mTitleBarView;
    private ListView listView;
    private InformListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<Inform_item> inform_item_list;

    private Inform_dbHandler inform_dbHandler  = new Inform_dbHandler(getActivity());

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getActivity();
        mBaseView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inform_list, null);
        findView();
        init();

        return mBaseView;       
    }

    private void findView(){
        mTitleBarView=(TitleBarView) mBaseView.findViewById(R.id.title_bar);
        listView = (ListView)mBaseView.findViewById(R.id.inform_list);
    }

    private void init(){
        mTitleBarView.setCommonTitle(View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE);
        mTitleBarView.setTitleText(R.string.inform);

        inform_item_list = new ArrayList<Inform_item>();
        inform_item_list = inform_dbHandler.getAllInform();

        listAdapter = new InformListAdapter(getActivity(), inform_item_list);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

}
```

I think it might be this line is wrong:

```
private Inform_dbHandler inform_dbHandler  = 
    new Inform_dbHandler(getActivity());
```

But I don't know how to solve this problem? Can you help me? Thank you~

Comment: show `getAllInform` code

Comment: I konw what's wrong: I show "return convertView" at InformListAdapter rather than "return null"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify like this:

```
private Inform_dbHandler inform_dbHandler ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getActivity();
        mBaseView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inform_list, null);
        findView();
        init();
        Inform_dbHandler inform_dbHandler  = new Inform_dbHandler(getActivity());

        return mBaseView;       
    }
```

The problem is you are creating the object for dbhandler but that will be initialized before attaching to the activity. in that situation getActivity() method retuns null, so database will not be worked out.

then Best practice is if you want dbhelper class object globally initialize that object in

`OnAttach()` of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for `InformListAdapter` class you have only one mistake,

```
public class InformListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Inform_item> inform_item_list;

    public InformListAdapter(Activity activity,
            List<Inform_item> inform_item_list) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.inform_item_list = inform_item_list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inform_item_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inform_item_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inform_item, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inform_title);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.inform_timestamp);
        TextView content = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.inform_content);

        Inform_item inform_item = inform_item_list.get(position);

        title.setText(inform_item.get_title());
        timestamp.setText(inform_item.get_timestamp());
        content.setText(inform_item.get_content());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: But what is the issue?

Comment: Yea, could you please explain what was wrong and focus on the problem section.

Comment: and also initilize you dbHandler in `onCreate` method, The issue with `InformListAdapter` class was that you were returning null at the end of `getView`

Comment: Hum! I know what's wrong: I should return convertView at InformListAdapter rather than return null!